# I'm Using JsonUtility.ToJson() to save data of a Settings object, is there a way to save the objects within Settings?

Tags: unity-game-engine

To be more specific, I'm making a music program and have settings like Tempo, Key, etc. These are set by sliders, buttons, checkboxes, dropdowns, etc. I have a big settings class that stores all these values, and my program would save those settings to a Json string. However, when I loaded the Json, the sliders obviously don't change. So how would I best store the data of the slider? Right now it stores the memory reference to the slider, is there a way to make it store the actual object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to apply the values to the sliders, buttons and checkboxes after loading them from json.

You can't save actual objects as json, but you can save all properties that you need to rebuild the object after loading the json again.

Comment: I see. So I should take the values I loaded and plug them back into the sliders. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped to solve the problem.